# How to change SIM cards and login successfully with a Blackberry ID?

Tags: blackberry, smartphone, sim-card

I just started to develop for BlackBerry 6 and 7 and grasped the basic for programming but when testing an example that requires to change the SIM card to validate a new number I came across a problem, I can't login.

I'm using a SIM card provided at my workplace and I don't understand the problem. I created a BlackBerry ID and tried to login, but it gives the message "This is not a valid BlackBerry account". I can use this user to log in into their site and the device was connected to WiFi before I changed the SIM card so it should be connected to the Internet, the login screen doesn't give me an option to connect to Internet so I guess it's connected.

I tried to change the SIM card back to its original but now it shows again a login screen.

Does it mean that a SIM card is linked to a single BlackBerry ID?

I'm learning from a book and nothing about changing SIM cards is covered there and the BlackBerry site is offering more on developing for BlackBerry 10 so I don't know where to dig there to find a faq section or common problems with older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that the BB has decided, since you changed the SIM card, that you might have 'found' the phone, and put a new Sim in so that you can use it.  So you might not be the owner of the phone.  So you need to log in again to prove you are.

Make sure your SIM is BlackBerry BIS or BES provisioned, so the phone can use it to get on the Internet.  Alternatively, make sure you are on WiFi.

I have had this sort of problem even without a SIM in a phone.  Restarting the phone will sometimes cause the phone to ask for the credentials again.  If it has not got WiFi connectivity, then you can get stuck on that screen.

I do not understand the requirement to change the Sim card.  Can you explain what you mean by:
"requires to change the SIM card to validate a new number"

Comment: If the user changes sim card then we wipe the persistent objects stored in the device